# C++11 Getting error 'enum-type' does not name a type with boost 1.59 fileSystem

Tags: c++11, boost, enums

I am getting below error while compiling my code with C++11.
With previous standard It was working fine no compilation issue. (C++03)

signature of function:
boost::filesystem::copy_option::enum_type myFunc()

Error:
‘enum-type’ in ‘enum class boost::filesystem::copy_option’ does not name a type

boost version : 1.59 
compiler : gcc version: 4.8.5

I am thinking this might be due to enum class in C++11.
However I dont have any clues how to fix this.

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve] and read read up on [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the v. 1.59.0 Boost Filesystem documentation, we find that [`boost::filesystem::copy_option`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#copy_option) is defined as:

```
enum class copy_option
{
  none
  fail_if_exists = none,
  overwrite_if_exists
};
```

But `enum class` is a C++11 feature, so how did including that header ever work in C++03 mode at all?  Let's take a peek at the header [boost/filesystem/header.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp), where we see `copy_option` is defined (inside `boost::filesystem`) as:

```
BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM_START(copy_option)
  {none=0, fail_if_exists = none, overwrite_if_exists};
BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM_END
```

A bit of searching turns up that `BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM_START` and `BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM_END` are part of the Boost.Core library.  The [scoped_enum reference page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/scoped_enum.html) explains that its purpose is "to generate C++11 scoped enums if the feature is supported by the compiler, otherwise emulate it with C++03 constructs".  It also says `BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM_START` and `BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM_END` are deprecated.  So let's look a bit back in time.

As far as I can tell, these macros first appeared without any documentation besides the header file itself in Boost 1.40.0 [boost/detail/scoped_enum_emulation.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/boost/detail/scoped_enum_emulation.hpp).  It was used for the same purpose from Boost.Filesystem.

At the time, there was no `copy_option::none` value.  So if Boost.Config automagically defined `BOOST_NO_SCOPED_ENUMS`, the enum definition expanded to C++03 compatible code:

```
struct copy_option { enum enum_t
  { fail_if_exists, overwrite_if_exists };
};
```

Or if `BOOST_NO_SCOPED_ENUMS` was not defined, the same definition expanded to C++0x-only code (this was before C++11 was official):

```
enum class copy_option
  { fail_if_exists, overwrite_if_exists };
```

Both allow and require writing for example `copy_option::overwrite_if_exists`.  But with one problem: In C++03 mode, the type of that value is `copy_option::enum_t`, but in C++0x mode, the type is just `copy_option`.  So the scoped_enum_emulation.hpp header defined a third macro `BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM(EnumName)` which expands to `EnumName::enum_t` in C++03 mode or just `EnumName` in C++0x mode.  Though the C++03 version still has some issues such as implicit conversion to integer types....

To get code that would work in either case, it was recommended to use `BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM(EnumName)` whenever you need a variable declaration, function parameter, or function return type to be the scoped enum type.  This will still work, so you could fix your issue by writing

```
BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM(boost::filesystem::copy_option) myFunc();
```

But there are now other options to consider too.

Boost 1.44.0 switched from using `enum_t` to `enum_type`.  So this is the oldest your code could have started with.

Boost 1.50.0 changed the definition of the old macros `BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM_START` and `BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM_END`, made them deprecated, and introduced the new macros `BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM_DECLARE_BEGIN` and `BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM_DECLARE_END` instead.  They also introduced some documentation under [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/thread/emulations.html#thread.emulations.scoped_enums), which apparently also started using it.  Boost.Filesystem's `copy_option` still used the old macros, but the C++03 expansion with `BOOST_NO_SCOPED_ENUMS` defined became:

```
struct copy_option {
    typedef void is_boost_scoped_enum_tag;
    typedef int underlying_type;
    copy_option() {}
    explicit copy_option(underlying_type v) : v_(v) {}
    underlying_type get_underlying_value_() const { return v_; }
private:
    underlying_type v_;
    typedef copy_option self_type;
public:
    enum enum_type
      {none=0, fail_if_exists = none, overwrite_if_exists};
    enum_type get_native_value_() const { return enum_type(v_); }
    operator enum_type() const { return get_native_value_(); }
    friend bool operator ==(self_type lhs, self_type rhs) { return enum_type(lhs.v_)==enum_type(rhs.v_); }
    friend bool operator ==(self_type lhs, enum_type rhs) { return enum_type(lhs.v_)==rhs; }
    friend bool operator ==(enum_type lhs, self_type rhs) { return lhs==enum_type(rhs.v_); }
    friend bool operator !=(self_type lhs, self_type rhs) { return enum_type(lhs.v_)!=enum_type(rhs.v_); }
    friend bool operator !=(self_type lhs, enum_type rhs) { return enum_type(lhs.v_)!=rhs; }
    friend bool operator !=(enum_type lhs, self_type rhs) { return lhs!=enum_type(rhs.v_); }
    friend bool operator <(self_type lhs, self_type rhs) { return enum_type(lhs.v_)<enum_type(rhs.v_); }
    friend bool operator <(self_type lhs, enum_type rhs) { return enum_type(lhs.v_)<rhs; }
    friend bool operator <(enum_type lhs, self_type rhs) { return lhs<enum_type(rhs.v_); }
    friend bool operator <=(self_type lhs, self_type rhs) { return enum_type(lhs.v_)<=enum_type(rhs.v_); }
    friend bool operator <=(self_type lhs, enum_type rhs) { return enum_type(lhs.v_)<=rhs; }
    friend bool operator <=(enum_type lhs, self_type rhs) { return lhs<=enum_type(rhs.v_); }
    friend bool operator >(self_type lhs, self_type rhs) { return enum_type(lhs.v_)>enum_type(rhs.v_); }
    friend bool operator >(self_type lhs, enum_type rhs) { return enum_type(lhs.v_)>rhs; }
    friend bool operator >(enum_type lhs, self_type rhs) { return lhs>enum_type(rhs.v_); }
    friend bool operator >=(self_type lhs, self_type rhs) { return enum_type(lhs.v_)>=enum_type(rhs.v_); }
    friend bool operator >=(self_type lhs, enum_type rhs) { return enum_type(lhs.v_)>=rhs; }
    friend bool operator >=(enum_type lhs, self_type rhs) { return lhs>=enum_type(rhs.v_); }
};
```

Note they have now made the C++03 type `copy_option` into a class mostly compatible with the enum type it encloses.  Plus it in some cases acts more like a C++11 scoped enum: for example, if `opt` is a `copy_option`, you can't do `opt==1`.   So you might want to consider doing just

```
boost::filesystem::copy_option myFunc();
```

instead.  The biggest issue with that is that (because the old macros are used), the constructor of `copy_option` is explicit, so you must use direct-initialization and not copy-initialization to get from an enumerator value to a `copy_option`.  That is, `copy_option var = copy_option::fail_if_exists;` and `return copy_option::fail_if_exists;` won't work, but `copy_option var(copy_option::fail_if_exists);` and `return copy_option(copy_option::fail_if_exists);` would.

In Boost 1.53.0 the involved Boost.Config macro changed from `BOOST_NO_SCOPED_ENUMS` to `BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS`.

In Boost 1.56.0 the scoped enum support moved to Boost.Core, file boost/core/scoped_enum.hpp .